# Mysql search on high number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, doctrine, query-optimization

I try to import a relatively high number of data in a mysql database (around 6 millions entries coming from text files).

I have to check for each entry if there is not already a similar record in the database by comparing it with two text fields :

```sql
`ref` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
`labelCanonical` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
```

Files are processed by batches of N entries (for this example 10), and I do a single query to check for all duplicates in the batch, like so :

```sql
SELECT p.`ref`, p.`labelCanonical` 
FROM `rtd_piece` p 
WHERE (p.`ref` = "6569GX" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "fsc-principal") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569GY" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "fsc-principal") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569GZ" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "fsc-principal") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569H0" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "fsc-habitacle") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569H1" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "support-fsc") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569H2" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "fsc-injection") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569H4" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "fsc-injection") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569H8" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "faisceau-mot") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569H9" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "faisceau-mot") 
  OR (p.`ref` = "6569HA" AND p.`labelCanonical` = "fsc-principal")
```

I use Doctrine 2 (without Symfony), and I do this query using "NativeQuery".

This problem is, even with a 600k entries in the database, this query takes **730ms** *(or 6.7 seconds for a batch of 100 records)* to execute and it increases dramatically as records are added to the database.

I have no index on "ref" or "labelCanonical" fields for now, and I'm not sure if adding one will do any good with the kind of request I do.

Where I am wrong with this method so its so slow ?

***Edit to add more information about the process.***

I do an ajax query for each batch, also to give a feedback to the user.
When in the server side (PHP), I do the following procedure :

1) I seek on the current file on processing and extract next N records

2) I parse each line and add references and slugified labels to two different arrays

3) I try to get these records from the database to avoid duplicates :

```
$existing = array();
$results = getRepository('Piece')->findExistingPieces($refs, $labels);
for ($i = 0, $c = count($results); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $existing[] = $results[$i]['ref'].'|'.$results[$i]['labelCanonical'];
}
```

```php
public function findExistingPieces(array $refs, array $labels)
{
    $sql = '';
    $where = array();
    $params = array();

    for ($i = 0, $c = count($refs); $i < $c; ++$i) {
        $params[] = $refs[$i];
        $params[] = $labels[$i];
        $where[] = '(p.`ref` = ? AND p.`labelCanonical` = ?)';
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT p.`ref`, p.`labelCanonical` '.
           'FROM `rtd_piece` p '.
           'WHERE '.implode(' OR ', $where);

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addScalarResult('ref', 'ref');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('labelCanonical', 'labelCanonical');

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                  ->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
                  ->setParameters($params);
    return $query->getScalarResult();
}
```

4) I iterate through previously parsed data and check for duplicates :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbParsed; ++$i) {
    $data = $parsed[$i];

    if (in_array($data['ref'].'|'.$data['labelCanonical'], $existing)) {
        // ...
        continue ;
    }
    // Add record
    $piece = new PieceEntity;
    $piece->setRef($data['ref']);
    //...

    $em->persist($piece);
}
```

5) I flush at the end of the batch

I've added some "profiling" code to track the time being spent for each step, here the result :

```
0.00024509429931641 (0.245 ms) : Initialized
0.00028896331787109 (0.289 ms) : Start doProcess
0.00033092498779297 (0.331 ms) : Read and parse lines
0.0054769515991211 (5.477 ms) : Check existence in database
6.9432899951935 (6,943.290 ms) : Process parsed data
6.9459540843964 (6,945.954 ms) : Finilize
6.9461529254913 (6,946.153 ms) : End of process
6.9464020729065 (6,946.402 ms) : End doProcess
6.9464418888092 (6,946.442 ms) : Return result
```

The first number show microseconds elapsed since the beginning of the request, then the same time in milliseconds and then what is being done.

Comment: I'm 100% sure this is because you're wasting 1 I/O per 1 query. Can you show the code that inserts the data? Also, did you group anything in a transaction? It's good to group a few hundred inserts into a single transaction and flush it.

Comment: Another optimization that I'd do is determine the hash of the combination of the two columns and make it unique. During inserts, I'd provide this hash and I'd use `INSERT IGNORE` which would simplify your import process because you only have to insert, group a few hundred inserts in 1 transaction block and wait a bit for the script to end.

Comment: you could try to setup a combined index on p.ref AND p.labelCanonical. So the lookup for your SELECt should speed up.

Comment: I've added more details to the question, including some of the server side code. I'm looking for more information about how "INSERT IGNORE" works and I come back. Thanks.

Comment: You gave me an idea Olli, maybe create a column "hash" containing the md5() of `ref` and `labelCanonical` combined, it may speed up the process. Would it useful to add a FULLTEXT index to this column and change the request to a MATCH AGAINST ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but didn't I suggest that you create a unique index out of the hashed value of the two columns? :) anyway, it seems you got the general direction so good luck optimizing this insert procedure.

Comment: Yes that's right, sorry about that, and thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to add this unique "hash" column with a FULLTEXT index on it and I'll come back with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some refactoring, here it's what I came with :

I check for duplicates using a new field named "hash" like so :

```php
$existing = array();
$results = getRepository('Piece')->findExistingPiecesByHashes($hashes);
for ($i = 0, $c = count($results); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $existing[] = $results[$i]['hash'];
}
```

```php
public function findExistingPiecesByHashes(array $hashes)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT p.`ref`, p.`labelCanonical`, p.`hash` '.
           'FROM `rtd_piece` p '.
           'WHERE (p.`hash`) IN (?)';

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addScalarResult('ref', 'ref');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('hash', 'hash');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('labelCanonical', 'labelCanonical');

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                  ->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
                  ->setParameters(array($hashes));
    return $query->getScalarResult();
}
```

The hash is automatically updated in the model like so :

```php
// Entities/Piece.class.php

private function _updateHash()
{
    $this->hash = md5($this->ref.'|'.$this->labelCanonical);
}
```

My hash field has no FULLTEXT index because I use the InnoDB engine and MySQL version 5.5, and from what I've read InnoDB only supports FULLTEXT indexes since MySQL 5.6.

I don't have the feel to update MySQL right now, too many databases and websites runs on it, it would be disastrous if the update goes wrong.

BUT, even without indexing the field, the performance gain is incredible :

```
0.00024199485778809 (0.242) : Initialized
0.00028181076049805 (0.282) : Start doProcess
0.0003199577331543 (0.320) : Read and parse lines
0.088779926300049 (88.780) : Check existence in database
0.8656108379364 (865.611) : Process parsed data
0.94273900985718 (942.739) : Finilize
1.3771109580994 (1,377.111) : End of process
1.3795168399811 (1,379.517) : End doProcess
1.3795938491821 (1,379.594) : Return result
```

**And this is for a batch of 1000 with 650k records on the table**.

Before this optimization, it took 6.7s for a check of 100 records, so it's around 9 times faster !

At this speed I should be able to import all the data in 1h30-2h.

Thanks you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me suggest that you write this using row constructors:

```
SELECT p.`ref`, p.`labelCanonical` 
FROM `rtd_piece` p 
WHERE (p.`ref`, p.`labelCanonical`) IN  ( ('6569GX', 'fsc-principal'),
                                          ('6569GY', 'fsc-principal'),
                                          . . .
                                        );
```

This will not affect performance, but it is easier to read.  Then, you need an index, either `rtd_piece(ref, labelCanonical)` or `rtd_piece(labelCanonical, ref)`.

Comment: Thanks, in my answer below I've done it like you suggest. It's easier to read yes.

Comment: Hehe -- Gordon and I were just now discussion another example of `WHERE (a,b) IN (...)`.  I hand concluded that the optimizer was not smart enough to do a good job with such.